# Why does screen spin indefinitely when creating new deployment?

Tags: google-apps-script

When trying to create a new deployment of my project, the screen just loads forever and nothing happens. Has anyone seen this happen before with a Google App Script project?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click "Deploy".
2. Click "New Deployment"
3. Observe the screen just loads forever.

[image]

Comment: Usually, this is a transitional issue of Apps Script. You can try later, use a different browser, or clear cache and cookies. If the problem persists, you can report it to Google by following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#problems_errors).

Comment: I found the [status of Google](https://www.google.com/appsstatus/dashboard/), some services are down, and it might be affecting Google Apps Script.

Comment: So annoying.....